# Return array of values when querying single column instead of array of objects

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typeorm

When using the query builder in typeorm I do a select of a single column and I would like to get an array of values (In my particular case it would be an array of strings) but instead I get an array of objects where the key is the column name and the value is the row value.

For example the code:

```
this.createQueryBuilder('subscriptions')
  .select('id')
  .getRawMany()
```

Would return something like:

```
[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]
```

Instead of a simple array like `[1,2,3]`

Is there any way to obtain this array from the query? or the only way is to map the result of the query to extract the value?

Comment: whats the relation?

Comment: I'm doing some joins and where clauses on the actual query I want to make, but I think that the query that I put in the example applies to many cases and many tables. I just want to pick one column and return an array with the values of the rows of that column without it being an array of objects that just has the name of the column as the key

Comment: @EduardoFarrera, did you found the solution? I have the same issue

Comment: As far as I can tell after combing through basically the whole documentation, that is not possible Could be because of the "ORMness", after all, one of the points of ORM systems is to map your data to objects and returning an array of values erases that information. The easiest way to solve this is to just use map: `const arrayResults = queryResults.map((r) => r.id)`. Or if you have large amounts of data, [stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71451562/how-to-get-stream-typeorm-result-sql-server-by-query-method) it.

Comment: What if you use getMany instead?

Answer (score 1):

Only option you have is map

```js
const arrayResults = queryResults.map(r => r.id);
```