# How to get Stream TypeORM result (SQL Server) by query method?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sql-server-2008, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I need to get all data from the table in Stream format using Typeform.
Based on documentation it's possible to get stream data by calling the `createQueryBuilder` method.

```
await this.createQueryBuilder('log').where(`date <= :date`, { date }).stream();
```

For some reason, I can't use `createQueryBuilder`, in my case only the `query` method seems to be available.

Is it possible to get stream data using Typeform and query method? Like

```
await mssqlConnection.query('select * from table_name').stream();
```

Database is SQL Server.

Example of query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT accounts.PersonID,
          Email,
          FirstName,
          LastName,
          PersonVersion,
          AccountID,
          AccountVersion,
          AccountPayorRelID,
          AccountPayorRelVersion,
          SchoolID,
          IsHidden,
          SchoolName,
          G_PersonPhoneNumber.Phone,
          G_PersonAddress.*,
          ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + LTRIM(str(AR_ChildSchool.PersonID))
            FROM AR_ChildSchool
            INNER JOIN dbo.AR_Enrollment ON AR_ChildSchool.ChildSchoolID = AR_Enrollment.ChildSchoolID
            WHERE AR_ChildSchool.ChildSchoolID in (
                SELECT ChildSchoolId FROM AR_ChildRel WHERE AR_ChildRel.PersonID = accounts.PersonID
            ) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), '') as childIds,
          GETDATE() as createdAt
          FROM dbo.NurtureUserAccounts AS accounts
           LEFT JOIN G_PersonPhoneNumber ON accounts.PersonID = G_PersonPhoneNumber.PersonID AND G_PersonPhoneNumber.PhoneNumberTID = 1
           LEFT JOIN G_PersonAddress ON accounts.PersonID = G_PersonAddress.PersonID
          WHERE Email != '' AND IsHidden = 0
          ORDER BY  PersonVersion OFFSET 0 ROWS;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `stream()` with `createQueryBuilder()` but you'll have to manually unmarshall the chunks from the `data` handler.

Consider the following setup in SQL Server...

```sql
create database Example;
go

use Example;
go

create table dbo.Events (
    EventID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
    [Date] date not null,
    [Description] nvarchar(50) not null
);
go

insert dbo.Events ([Date], [Description]) values
    ('2022-01-01', N'New Year''s Day'),
    ('2022-03-14', N'Pi Day'),
    ('2022-09-19', N'International Talk Like a Pirate Day'),
    ('2022-12-15', N'Christmas Day');
go
```

When executing the following TypeORM code...

```
//app.ts
'use strict';
import { Column, Connection, createConnection, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { ReadStream } from "typeorm/platform/PlatformTools";

@Entity({schema: "dbo", name: "Events"})
export class Events {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    EventID: number;

    @Column()
    Date: Date;

    @Column({ length: 50 })
    Description: string;
}

const many = async (connection: Connection) => {
    const events: Events[] = await connection
        .getRepository(Events)
        .createQueryBuilder("e")
        .getMany();
    console.log(`many: ${JSON.stringify(events)}`);
}

const single = async (connection: Connection) => {
    const event: Events = await connection
        .getRepository(Events)
        .createQueryBuilder("e")
        .where("e.EventID = :eventId", { eventId: 3 })
        .getOne();
    console.log(`single: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
}

const streaming = async (connection: Connection) => {
    const stream: ReadStream = await connection
        .getRepository(Events)
        .createQueryBuilder("e")
        .stream();
    stream.on("data", chunk => {
        console.log(`streaming: ${JSON.stringify(chunk)}`);
    });
}

createConnection({
    name: "default",
    type: "mssql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 1433,
    username: "sa",
    password: "MyStrongPassw0rd",
    database: "Example",
    entities: [
        Events
    ],
    extra: {
        options: {
            encrypt: false
        },
    },
    logging: true
}).then(connection => {
    single(connection);
    many(connection);
    streaming(connection);
});
```

You'll see the following output from `single`:

```json
single: {"EventID":3,"Date":"2022-09-18T14:00:00.000Z","Description":"International Talk Like a Pirate Day"}
```

The following from `many`:

```json
many: [{"EventID":1,"Date":"2021-12-31T14:00:00.000Z","Description":"New Year's Day"},{"EventID":2,"Date":"2022-03-13T14:00:00.000Z","Description":"Pi Day"},{"EventID":3,"Date":"2022-09-18T14:00:00.000Z","Description":"International Talk Like a Pirate Day"},{"EventID":4,"Date":"2022-12-14T14:00:00.000Z","Description":"Christmas Day"}]
```

And the following (multiple lines) from `streaming`:

```json
streaming: {"e_EventID":1,"e_Date":"2021-12-31T14:00:00.000Z","e_Description":"New Year's Day"}
streaming: {"e_EventID":2,"e_Date":"2022-03-13T14:00:00.000Z","e_Description":"Pi Day"}
streaming: {"e_EventID":3,"e_Date":"2022-09-18T14:00:00.000Z","e_Description":"International Talk Like a Pirate Day"}
streaming: {"e_EventID":4,"e_Date":"2022-12-14T14:00:00.000Z","e_Description":"Christmas Day"}
```

Note the `e_` prefixes on the property names, which comes from `.createQueryBuilder("e")`.

Comment: Thanks but I think it's not possible to transform my request to createQueryBuilder format. I added a query example to the question, please see updates.

Comment: @VolodymyrZh you can use `connection.createQueryBuilder().select("*").from("(SELECT ...)", "alias").stream()`, which will run the following SQL query: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) "alias"`, which should be equivalent to your desired query that you can put in place of `...`